# Where to download additional dynamic, external content used by Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We have developed an Eclipse feature with some plugins which, upon start or configuration change, it requires to download some external, non OSGI, content which is then used by the plugins themselves.
We currently create an additional folder inside the eclipse installation folder where such content is downloaded and unpacked and then use it from there.

While the location itself is working perfectly fine I wonder if we should be using a more appropriate location within the Eclipse folder structure or if we are violating some convention we are unaware of.

```
<eclipse root>
 +- .eclipseextension
 +- configuration
 +- features
 +- p2
 +- plugins
 +- readme
 +- <custom folder here>     <-- is this "correct"?
 | | <custom content here>  
 | .eclipseproduct
 | artifacts.xml
 | eclipsec.exe
 | notice.html
 | eclipse.exe
 | eclipse.ini
```

Comment: The 'state location' is the correct place for this data.

Comment: I made a edit to explain there are basically2 types of data cached and "extracted data". The cache is safe to remove and can be shared between eclipse installs where the extracted data is eclipse instance specific and should not be tempered with by third parties.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [plugin state location](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_do_plug-ins_store_their_state%3F) directory that you can find using the getStateLocation() method on your plugin class.  It's supposed to be for cached data that can be deleted and rebuilt and that's very much like the downloaded content you describe.

As you say, what you're doing now does work, but it makes the assumption that the install directory is on the local machine and I think that's not necessarily a given.

Comment: Cool! That will also imply the downloaded content is available within the workspace but different workspaces will have different plugin content, right? That will also mean if all workspaces use the same plugin content I will end up having multiple copies... Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @RobertoLoGiacco I believe so, but that may change in a future version - the state location directory being based on the workspace type and location vs being based on the installation type and directory, that is

Comment: The link you refer to states " The install directory must be treated as read-only, as a multi-user installation of Eclipse will typically use a single install location to serve many users. However, your plug-in can still store read-only information there, such as images, templates, default settings, and documentation. " This is exactly what the ArduinoPlugin folder contains. Gcc compilers, documentation, not to modify configuration files,